# How do I use the category when writing to Debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I added debug lines in my code as follows:

```
Debug.WriteLine("some debug text", "mycategory");
```

The debug text is shown in the `Output` window as expected.

However, how can I add the category to the list of categories shown in the dropdown list `Show output from`?

Comment: my out pout is **mycategory**: some debug text, so i can not reproduce your problem

Comment: As @nbk said code works fine and shows up with default ConsoleTraceListener. Please make sure the question contains an [mre] (i.e. you may have reconfigured/reimplemented listeners for all we know). You may want to re-read docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=net-7.0 and related listeners articles to get more clarity how whole system works.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything,

Maybe you missed where the category is displayed - it is just before the debug text:

[image: Example for category]